# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/dynamodb/type/DynamoDBTypeFactory

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

Can anyone please help to resolve this issue?
Detail log:

```
13:49:50.622 [8275e9b3-01c9-499d-bc48-e1a2f06bdf5e Thread-1] ERROR hive.ql.exec.DDLTask - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/dynamodb/type/DynamoDBTypeFactory
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.util.HiveDynamoDBUtil.getHiveToDynamoDBTypeMapping(HiveDynamoDBUtil.java:69)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBSerDe.initialize(DynamoDBSerDe.java:74)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.AbstractSerDe.initialize(AbstractSerDe.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.initializeSerDe(SerDeUtils.java:533)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:450)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.getDeserializer(MetaStoreUtils.java:437)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializerFromMetaStore(Table.java:281)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getDeserializer(Table.java:263)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getColsInternal(Table.java:641)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Table.getCols(Table.java:624)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:831)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:867)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.createTable(DDLTask.java:4356)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask.execute(DDLTask.java:354)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:199)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2183)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1839)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1232)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:255)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runInternal(SQLOperation.java:293)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.run(Operation.java:320)
```

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org/apache/hadoop/dynamodb/type/DynamoDBTypeFactory

Comment: Need more details. please add DDL/commands you are using.

Comment: Looks like a simple unmet dependency. Find out where that class is and add it to your classpath

Comment: You are missing the jar, add it to your classpath.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)